# Spring Cloud OAuth2 SSO and refresh token

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

Here is the scenario:

Web App (webapp) authentication uses OAuth Authorization Server SSO 
by setting spring.oauth2.sso.* properties.

User authenticates and webapp now have user credentials and access_token. Application then uses this token to call certain microservices on the backend.

When token expires it will eventually get 403 Unathorized.

Since we dont have refresh token should we just force user to login again? 
What if we want user to stay logged in longer then token's TTL?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, absent having a refresh token, the user will need to login again as this is the only way to get a new access token without it.